# How to use multi stored procedures in one query to select from other tables

Tags: sql-server

I am running 2 virtual machines. Computer A has microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 2008 (running as admin).... Computer B has FactoryTalk View Studio and Visual Basic.

I am using Computer B to create a HMI that calls and collects data from computer A.   Everything is connected, working properly and now i am stuck on being able to write effective stored procedures to do what i want it to do.

So I have a table that has a list of coffees.

```
1= kona, 
2= coco, 
3= etc., etc,...
```

On my HMI I have a drop down list that has the names of the different coffees. When Kona for example is selected, it calls to computer A and executes the stored procedure. Right now, i am stuck with being able to use the list to select only the name i select and to aquire only this data.

On computer A i put enumerations 1 through 10 (1=kona). 'Status1' is my variable that is beings passed along.

But when i set status1 = 1 through 10 in my case structure, it doesnt change as i select the names from the coffee in the drop down list. Right now the code is set up to select everything in that table.

So if i go to my list and select kona or other coffees, the same data appears.  i would like different data when i select different coffees. i cant seem to wrap my head around the logic or the know how in being able to do this.

```
 USE [COFFEE_BRANDS]
 GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 ALTER PROC [dbo].[spGETQUANTITY] @status1 INT, @status2 INTAS SET NOCOUNT ON 
 DECLARE @RETURN int

 SELECT * FROM DBO.DESCRIBE 
 SELECT @RETURN = @@rowcount 
 FROM DBO.DESCRIBE
 RETURN  @RETURN
```

Comment: What is the purpose of @status1 and 2? You could use them in a where clause on the select statement assuming you can execute the proc and provide those values. Do a search on parameters.

Comment: Why would you expect it to change, you didn't put a where clause on your select statement.